# Both Internet and Wifi not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04

I have currently problems with connecting to the internet with my Lenovo ThinkPad running Ubuntu 20.04. I apologize in advance because I am a big beginner and all the other posts I saw on the subject did not helped me to identify the problem. Also, it will be difficult for me to post command line outputs because I am using another computer to post this.

Thanks a lot!

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78) Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:1010] Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl


$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    4.530066] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.548037] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.548040] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    4.549380] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.606643] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    4.618070] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.619254] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    4.680246] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: f8:94:c2:5c:89:8d
[    4.757554] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.740810] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.876876] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.944671] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

Comment: Did WiFi work before. or is it a fresh install?

Comment: It worked before.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: try to boot with a previous kernel using grub menu. Wi-Fi may work there.

Comment: Ok I will try to find a way to copy the output of the command here. I will check the kernels as well.

Comment: It is quite easy to copy output. You can copy and paste it to a text file.

Comment: 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:1010]
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: Yes, it is a dual boot.

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl` TO YOUR QUESTION. PLEASE DON'T POST IT TO COMMENTS.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I edited my question.

Comment: The device is working. I see no problems.

Comment: Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Does anyone else see how I could solve this?